# Error: TypeError: response.replace is not a function

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a plugin which returns the parts prices from couple of websites. The plugin is showing error from last few days

```
"Error: TypeError: response.replace is not a function"                 (index):338
at Object.success ((index):320:60)
    at c (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2:28447)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2:29192)
    at l (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2:80176)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2:82630)
```

It was working fine and I have no idea why this error is showing.

Here is my code.

```
 function getPartNumber(WP_REST_Request $request) {
        $oePart = $request['oePart'];
        $provider = $request['provider'];
        $notFoundText = 'Not found';
        $part = $notFoundText;
        $error = false;
        $errorMessage = null;
        $price = null;

        try {
            if(strcmp($provider, 'donaldson') === 0) {
                $part = getDonaldsonPartNumber($oePart, $notFoundText);
            } else if(strcmp($provider, 'mann-filter') === 0) {
                $part = getMannFilterPartNumber($oePart, $notFoundText);
            } else if(strcmp($provider, 'cummins') === 0) {
                $part = getCumminsPartNumber($oePart, $notFoundText);
            } else if(strcmp($provider, 'baldwin') === 0) {
                $part = getBaldwinPartNumber($oePart, $notFoundText);
            } else if(strcmp($provider, 'luberfiner') === 0) {
                $part = getLuberfinerPartNumber($oePart, $notFoundText);
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $error = true;
            $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
        }

        $found = !(strcmp($part, $notFoundText) === 0);

        if($found) {
            $pricelist = loadPricelist();
            $price = $pricelist[$part];
        }

    
        $response = new WP_REST_Response(array(
            'oePart' => $oePart,
            'provider' => $provider,
            'part' => $part,
            'found' => $found,
            'error' => $error,
            'errorMessage' => $errorMessage,
            'price' => $price,
        ));
    
    
        $response->set_status(200);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
        return $response;
    }
```

I Have no idea why the object error is showing. can anyone help me to figure out the issue.